# BeyondCompare for .properties

Tags: java, file, configuration, editor, beyondcompare

I am using BeyondCompare to compare files and am very happy with it. However I'd like to be comparing and cross-editing two .properties files as well. The specific is obvious - I do not care about the order of name/value pairs but I care about duplications etc. Does anyone knows (or also needs) such an application?

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick to [sort the properties by key name when saving](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0614.html).

Or sort both files before comparing them.

Comment: I know that trick. But those files have hundreds of sharing owners even in production. Hardly all of them will agree.

Comment: And why would they not agree?

Comment: Because information in these files is historically grouped differently - sometimes by functions, sometimes by release. Developers and even more operations want to find the information where is was

Comment: I see, that is if you create the file manually. What I usually do is create the file within the program. In this case, using java.util.Properties.store() will not keep the order.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works pretty good for me.

As far as I can tell, the only problem with this approach is that when you save any change made using Beyond Compare, the properties file get all messed up; so you need to select the File format "<default>" before save or make the changes outside of Beyond Compare.

Based on [the message #2](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?13877-compare-text-to-first-character) and the link [it contains](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3). I'm using BC v3.3.13

The trick is to create a special file format:

1. Go to the menu `Tools / File Formats...`

   - create (click on lower left `new` button) or ...
   - modify one (selecting it)
2. Set a proper name for it: `Properties`
3. In the `General` tab set the mask: `*.properties`
4. In the `Conversion` tab set `Sorting`
5. In the `Gramar` tab

   - key=value

     1. Click `New` button
     2. Set a proper name: `Equal sign to the end`
     3. Click in the radio button named `Delimited`
     4. Put an equal sign (`=`) in the `Text from:` field
     5. Set the checkbox named `Stop at end of line`
   - comments

     1. Click `New` button
     2. Set a proper name: `Comments`
     3. Click in the radio button named `Delimited`
     4. Put a sharp sign (`#`) in the `Text from:` field
     5. Set the checkbox named `Stop at end of line`
6. Click on the `Save` button or press `Alt-S`
7. Close the shown dialog
8. Press the reload toolbar icon, or select manually the new file format

[image: Comparison example]

9. You can tell Beyond compare the text after the equal sign and after the sharp sign are unimportant:

   1. Click in the `rules` tool bar icon (the guy with a hat) (is shown inside a blue oval in the previous image)
   2. Go to the `Importance` tab
   3. Remove the check in both grammar elements:

[image]

```
4. Press the `Ok` button
```

- Note Beyond Compare shows the file format in the two red ovals I added to the first  image
- Note Beyond Compare tells you the files are NOT shown as they are in the file system, but they are converted (sorted) if you see the text to the right of the ovals shown.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing using the `Sorted` format.

[image: BC Sorted Format]

Comment: I understand that for this comparison to be effective sorting should be involved. The problem is that the tool after Beyond Compare style editing (copy to the right, copy to the left etc.) should leave the edited files as close to their initial state as possible.

Comment: @Dima, the sorting is logical, it doesn't change the file itself.

Comment: I referred to Beyond Compare because its UI is very convenient in that you may by almost one click move a selected line(s) from one side to another so changing the file(s) is the aim of activity discussed.

Comment: If I apply BeyondCompare to a long and messy config files from different releases of the application it does not work as it would if it took in account that the information is strictly name=value (+ comments of course) and does not display files name aligned to name. That is desired. So you make you judgement, do copy from any side to another if necessary and commit. The files may be changed but preferably in some "minimal" way.